# Single Executable and different services

Tags: c++, windows-services

I want to have Single Executable part of multiple services. i.e. name of the service will be different but the executable will be different. 
How Do I identify the which service is called in `ServiceMain`

Comment: Executable different?  You probably mean the executable will the identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.
You should give every service its own ServiceMain function.

An example is given on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

When this application is run with the "INSTALL" argument, it registers itself as a service using the CreateService function.  If your executable offers multiple services, you need to call CreateService multiple times.

When the application is run without the "INSTALL" argument, it fills a DispatchTable and passes it to StartServiceCtrlDispatcher.  If your executable supports multiple services, your DispatchTable will contain multiple entries.  Give every entry a different ServiceMain function and Windows will call the correct function.